# Separate item/details tables - is it bad design approach for DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My use case is displaying list view of items and details view for each item with more information. Data required for item display in a list would be 2KB at max and additional item details would vary in a range of 2KB to 20KB. Currently all item related data is stored in a single entry. Would it be sensible optimisation to split this into separate tables with one to one relationship? Are there any downsides except the fact that I have to update to tables at once and use TransactWrite to keep connection consistent?

Comment: single table with sort key to differentiate between the two records. PK is the item ID, sk is also the item id or "item" or similar for the list record. For the details record you can do the PK as the item ID, and the SK as "details" or similar. Then you can query the list entry separate from the details entry to avoid incurring extra RCUs when all you want is the list entry. For the details page you can avoid storing the list view fields again because a single query for just the PK will give you the list and details records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting records with 1:1 relationship into separate tables is a DynamoDB anti-pattern. As [AWS says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-relational-modeling.html):

> (1) Schema flexibility lets DynamoDB store complex hierarchical data within a single item. (2) Composite key design lets it store related items close together on the same table.

If your query patterns include requests for item heavy detail records separately from summary info, you may benefit from separating out the summary and detail records *in a single table*.

| PK | SK | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1-ID | Summary |  |
| Item1-ID | Detail |  |
| Item2-ID | Summary |  |
| Item2-ID | Detail |  |
| Item2-ID | Detail#History#2021-11-16T13:00:00 | Option to add item history |

`query` operations:

- **Item1 all**: `PK=Item1ID and SK>""` (2 records)
- **Item1 Summary**: `PK=Item1ID and SK=Summary` (1 record)
- **Item1 Details**: `PK=Item1ID and SK=Details` (1 record)
- **Item2 Detail** current + history: `PK=Item2ID and SK begins_with(Details)` (multiple)

The trickier optimisation is retrieving many `Summary` records.  For low record volumes, a `scan` may be tolerable.  For low query volumes, a secondary index with `Summary` or `Summary#Active`
(or some other subdivision to [add ever-important cardinality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-uniform-load.html)) might be a tolerable way to `query`.  Or you can periodically cache list results in a separate record if item create volumes are low.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am using Amplify and it seems like with Amplify the only possible way(without writing all resolvers by yourself) is to have separate tables and I think it is fine in my case(I never need to "join" these tables). But assuming I can go with single table design like you displayed is it good kind of optimisation? Can you outline pros/cons of having single record vs having summary/details records?

Comment: Glad to help!  I think of the popular [single-table design](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-single-table-design-with-amazon-dynamodb/) as the default, to be used unless good reasons can be found _not_ to.  Splitting records into summary/detail has a payoff if the payloads are heavy,  but is more complex.   Suggestion:  If you use [generic key names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html) like `PK` and `SK`, you start with single record design and split them later if over-fetching becomes a real problem.